# Scale Cassandra with copying data manually

Tags: cassandra, scaling

I created an AMI from my cassandra machine and then launched a new instance. After making config changes(setting the seed node to the first one, and setting auto_bootstrap: false) when I start cassandra and do a nodetool status it shows data on the both the nodes. I just want to know if the cluster actually knows that both nodes have the data and if a request comes can route it to the second node also.

As without manually copying data, the streaming is actually not getting completed. It somehow manages to fail after a certain period of time and then I have to again run 'nodetool bootstrap resume' to restart bootstraping process which again fails.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this should work this way (all the copying thing).

Why you can't perform normal bootstrapping? What are error messages in the logs when you try to do it? What is RF of your keyspace?

In addition to your data, Cassandra also saves information about the node on disk, all the system tables, for example node id, so you can't just replicate the image. If you copied cassandra image, and just changed config, this wouldn't work, you should delete all data prior to starting the node and joining to cluster.

EDIT:

**If you going with auto_bootstrap: off**

1. Remove **all the data** from the new server (both data and commit log directories).
2. Start the node, and after it joins, run rebuild.
3. Run repair after the process is finished.

**If you going with auto_bootstrap: on**

1. Remove **all the data** from the new server (both data and commit log directories).
2. Start the node and monitor the bootstraping.

Before trying these, remove the node you can't add from the cluster.

Comment: I am trying to do normal bootstraping but it stops after some time. There is no error in the logs or anything like that. Replication factor is 2.

Comment: After it stops bootstrapping I try doing 'nodetool bootstrap resume' and then again it starts streaming from the start only, and basically streaming same files again and again. I am stuck in this for one week but the process doesn't get completed.

Comment: I am going with the second part. I actually got an error this time : "WARN  [STREAM-IN-/172.30.0.120] 2017-05-08 11:31:59,733 StreamSession.java:641 - [Stream #ec4190b0-33b0-11e7-a5c4-fdb405d849ac] Retrying for following error
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown column commentid during deserialization" . I dont know which table it is talking about and how I can fix this error.

Comment: Did you removed all the data prior to bootstraping?

Comment: Yes, I deleted the 'data' folder completely. Should I remove some other directory/file also.

Comment: Yes, commitlog files,

Comment: commitlog files are present in the data folder only. Anyway I fixed it by transferring table's data to a new table and then dropping the table. Now the bootstrapping is completed and the node is up and normal state.